# More than one App_Code Folder in asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have a asp.net website and i want to test it on a domain.
The problem is I have already a site hosted on it and i cannot change it.

So I tried to create a sub-directory and uploaded my project in it.

The problem here arises with the web.config file as i want the inner project to link to another some other database.
Also the app_code folder is different for the inner project.

I thought of creating a sub-domain, but cannot do so, as i have no permissions.

Please help with some solution.

Comment: well what's the config look like show an example of the connection string

Comment: So you created a sub directory, but not a separate virtual directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `app_code` and `web.config` file in every folder. There is no issue in doing that.

But for web.config file there are some `restriction` about tag used in sub folder web.cofig file. A useful link

http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway//10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to clear your connection strings on the inner project web.config and add the new connection string.

In the "inner" project, add `<clear />` inside the `<connectionStrings>` node and then add your connection string in with test db connection string after they are cleared. This way it will not pick up the outer (live) site web.config connection string.

Warning - testing on a live site can always be tricky. Be careful!